# necessity of 'event

Tags: vhdl

I have used below statement, frequently. However, I wonder

```
  if ( clock'event and clock = '1' ) then 
             [do something]
```

we really need to write clock'event in above statement ? 
If yes, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *could* get the simulation to work perfectly without the `clock'event` condition, but the synthesis will come out wrong.

The IEEE standard on synthesizable VHDL *requires* that you add `clock'event`. 
It is commonly accepted good practice to write `if rising_edge(clock)` instead. This conveys your intention a lot better. Both `rising_edge` and `falling_edge` functions are allowed as synthesizable VHDL constructs.

For simulation:

```
process (clock) is
-- stuff
begin
if clock='1' then -- EVIL! don't do this
  -- do things
end if;
end process;
```

Assuming that `clock` just switches from '0' to '1' and back (no meta-values), the *behavior* would be identical to what you'd get with a `clock'event` condition. Again, this will not synthesize to what you want! You'll probably get a latch, not a D flip-flop.

(Bonus points for whomever tries to synthesize this and gets back with the results!)

Answer (score -3):

Yes, otherwise the following code executes the entire time your clock signal is high, not just at the rising edge of the clock.

Comment: Not true, the process is only triggered when one of the signals in the sensitivity lists change.